# Defining two o more functions in karate-config.js

Tags: javascript, function, karate, polyglot-markup

My karate-config.js is:

```
function config(){
    return karate.read('classpath:' + env_file());
}

function env_file(){
    var env_file = karate.env;
    if(!env_file){
        env_file = 'local.yml';
    }
    return 'env/' + env_file;
}
```

That was working fine until I upgraded my Java version to 17.

Now I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:5:0 Expected ) but found function
```

Is it possible now to define two functions in the same file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It was never supposed to have been supported, I'm surprised it worked.

Also refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file